# Laravel 5 addClassMap

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-5

Does anybody know, how I can do a similar thing in Laravel 5 version and where?

```
 $loader = require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
    $loader->addClassMap(array(
        'Illuminate\Cookie\Guard' => __DIR__ . '/overrides/Illuminate/Cookie/Guard.php',
        'Illuminate\Session\Store' => __DIR__ . '/overrides/Illuminate/Session/Store.php'
    ));
```

This one was done in the Laravel 4 version in bootstrap.php file.
Exactly what I want to do is to override existing class.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Hello you can do this in

**bootstrap/autoload.php**

but better do this using composer.

Comment: Thanks for help. :)
I have added in th ecomposer.json and it works: 
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/Overrides"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },